# CS50 pset4 recover > program is free of memory errors

Tags: c, memory-leaks, cs50

I finished writing the program that recovers photos from a memory card and it's working properly
But there is an error closing the "output"file.
I just want to know where to write another "fclose"

This is the error:

:( program is free of memory errors
Cause
valgrind tests failed; see log for more information.
Log
running valgrind --show-leak-kinds=all --xml=yes --xml-file=/tmp/tmpie2_4mb5 -- ./recover card.raw...
checking that program exited with status 0...
checking for valgrind errors...
23,128 bytes in 49 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1: (file: recover.c, line: 35)

the problem in " output = fopen(fileName, "w"); "
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check command-line arguments
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open files and determine scaling factor
    FILE* input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE* output = NULL; //output_file
    typedef uint8_t BYTE;
    BYTE buffer[BLOCK_SIZE]; //buffer = 512
    char fileName[8]; // =malloc
    int count = 0; //count image

    while (fread(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, sizeof(BYTE), input))
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer [3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            sprintf(fileName, "%03i.jpg", count);
            output = fopen(fileName, "w");
            count++;
        }
        if (output != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, sizeof(BYTE), output);
        }
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to close `output` each time before you open a new file (except for the first file).

Comment: Just _above_ the `output = fopen(fileName, "w");` line, do: `if (output != NULL) fclose(output);`

Comment: I got it , Thank you all for the help